# How to check out & check in the file from TFS using C# code?

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to create a Window Form Application which checks out, make some edits to the file & checks in the file in TFS.

I am able to do these operation by using below code. Only problem I am facing is in getting the `tf.exe` path dynamically. I don't want the path of `tf.exe` to be hard coded in solution. The `tf.exe` which I am trying to open is in Visual Studio 2017 folder.

```
foreach (string path in FilePaths)
{
  var proc = new Process
  {
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
       FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 
       14.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe",
       Arguments = "checkout " + path,
       UseShellExecute = false,
       RedirectStandardOutput = true,
       CreateNoWindow = true
    }
  };
 proc.Start();
}
```

The path provided in `FileName` should be dynamically fetched.

Comment: You can simply add settings to your application and configure it with open file dialog.

Comment: Btw, you say VS2017 (which is version 15.x) but opening `tf.exe` from previous VS2015 (14.x), see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#History). Also there should be many registry entries for VS installation, try to search for one which returns needed path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options:

1) Add a function that check where `tf.exe` installed and return the location (little ugly and you need update the function when new VS version is releases):

```
private string GetTfLocation()
{
    string tfPath = "";
    // For VS 2015
    if (File.Exists(tfPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 2014\Common7\IDE]tf.exe"))
        return tfPath;
    // For VS 2017 Professional version
    if (File.Exists(tfPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundaion\Team Explorer\Tf.exe"))
        return thPath;
    // And list all VS versions like above
    return null;
}
```

2) Ask the user to enter the location or which VS version he has and generate the version (in the second option need also to update the code with each new VS version):

Create a new TextBox, give a name (for example: `tfExeTxtBox`), in your code get the value:

```
string tfExeLoacation = tfExeTxtBox.Text;
```

3) Use TFS DLL's to do the actions and not start `tf.exe` process:

You need 2 DLL's (available in NuGet):

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client
```

Now you can do all TFVC action, for example:

```
TfsTeamProjectcollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectColletion(new Uri("tfs-server-url"));
VersionControlServer versionControl = (VersionControlServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));
Workspace workspace = versionControl.CreateWorkspace("newWorkSpace", "user name");
// Add to pending changes
workspace.PendAdd("workspace path");
var changes = workspace.GetPendingChanges();
// Check In
workspace.CheckIn(changes, "comment");
```